# Not Able to Create Trigger on SQL Table due to 'The specified event type(s) is/are not valid on the specified target object.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger on a table and I am encountering the issue above as a syntax error in SQL studios and get the below error when running the SQL statement:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdatePo, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 18]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT'

Here is the trigger I am trying to create:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tiTrigger
ON dbo.TABLE_ONE
AFTER [INSERT]
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @po_state VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @po_number VARCHAR(255)

    SELECT @po_state = order_state FROM inserted
    SELECT @po_number = po_number FROM inserted

    UPDATE TABLE_TWO
    SET PO_Status = @po_state
    WHERE PO_Number = @po_number
GO
```

Comment: Do you have a DDL trigger named UpdatePo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this failed is you need to remove the square brackets around INSERT, it is not an object name.

However, your trigger is broken. It has a MAJOR logical flaw that only one row will ever be inserted. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation. You need to rewrite this as a set based approach. This simple update can and should be done without any variables at all, just a simple join.

Doing this set based would be something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tiTrigger
   ON  dbo.TABLE_ONE
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t
    set PO_Status = i.order_state
    from TABLE_TWO t
    join inserted i on i.po_number = t.PO_Number
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the answer.